# Does image data get erased when uploaded?

Tags: discussion, images

I often upload photos of my house and neighborhood when asking questions.

Does the meta data associated with these photos (such as geo data) get erased when they are posted?

I wouldn't want someone to download the picture and be able to get location data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this [Imgur help page](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/201746817-Post-privacy), it should be.

> - Due to privacy concerns, EXIF data/metadata is removed on upload. There is no setting available to retain the data.

According to this [post over on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263504/133749), the meta data is indeed removed.

> On the side note, I would also like to point out that imgur will strip the EXIF data once the image is uploaded to their server.

You can see for yourself, using a service like [metapicz](http://metapicz.com/). Grab a link to one of your images, paste it in the field on metapicz, and click Go!  You should see that all the meta data is gone.

> [image: Image meta data removed]

However, if you post an image link from a third-party image hosting site, it would depend on the policies of that third-party.